# Having trouble finding the right JSON request

Tags: json

I will appologise in advance if I am being really stupid here, but I cant find the right syntax to extract some data from a JSON return.  The following is the returned JSON data:

```
    {
"version":"1.0",
"encoding":"UTF-8",
"feed":{
"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
"xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/",
"xmlns$gsx":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended",
"id":{
"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AhySzEddwIC1dEN6bnNQYkRlVE50RlBRLUQ5YlZhNUE/1/public/basic"
},
"updated":{
"$t":"2012-12-03T10:33:13.778Z"
},
"category":[
{
"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
"term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
}
],
"title":{
"type":"text",
"$t":"Sheet1"
},
"link":[
{
"rel":"alternate",
"type":"text/html",
"href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key\u003d0AhySzEddwIC1dEN6bnNQYkRlVE50RlBRLUQ5YlZhNUE"
},
{
"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed",
"type":"application/atom+xml",
"href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AhySzEddwIC1dEN6bnNQYkRlVE50RlBRLUQ5YlZhNUE/1/public/basic"
},
{
"rel":"self",
"type":"application/atom+xml",
"href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AhySzEddwIC1dEN6bnNQYkRlVE50RlBRLUQ5YlZhNUE/1/public/basic?alt\u003djson"
}
],
"author":[
{
"name":{
"$t":"rourkie"
},
"email":{
"$t":"rourkie@gmail.com"
}
}
],
"openSearch$totalResults":{
"$t":"1"
},
"openSearch$startIndex":{
"$t":"1"
},
"entry":[
{
"id":{
"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AhySzEddwIC1dEN6bnNQYkRlVE50RlBRLUQ5YlZhNUE/1/public/basic/cn6ca"
},
"updated":{
"$t":"2012-12-03T10:33:13.778Z"
},
"category":[
{
"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
"term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
}
],
"title":{
"type":"text",
"$t":"5872.64"
},
"content":{
"type":"text",
"$t":"change: 3.6"
},
"link":[
{
"rel":"self",
"type":"application/atom+xml",
"href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AhySzEddwIC1dEN6bnNQYkRlVE50RlBRLUQ5YlZhNUE/1/public/basic/cn6ca"
}
]
}
]
}
}
```

I am trying to extract the "change" figure, with the following:

```
feed.entry[4].content.$t
```

but it just keeps returning an error.

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong??

Thanks

Comment: What error is it returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONLint - http://jsonlint.com/ - is pretty handy for this.

The JSON you posted only has one object in the entry array (unless you just posted it as an example)...so it would be:

```
feed.entry[0].content.$t
```

Comment: In addition to JSONLint, may I recommend [http://jsonviewer.stack.hu](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu) as a great way to view the tree of a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Using json2csharp.com (http://json2csharp.com/) You can paste in json and it will give you a class matching the json allowing you to easily parse it.  Check [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c) on how to use JsonConvert.  I believe you can find it in nuget packages.  Keep in mind the class I have pasted below will not work directly, because of the naming of some of the fields in the json.  You may have to rename them manually and map them.

```
public class Id
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Updated
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string scheme { get; set; }
    public string term { get; set; }
}

public class Title
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public Email email { get; set; }
}

public class OpenSearchTotalResults
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class OpenSearchStartIndex
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Id2
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Updated2
{
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Category2
{
    public string scheme { get; set; }
    public string term { get; set; }
}

public class Title2
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Link2
{
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public Id2 id { get; set; }
    public Updated2 updated { get; set; }
    public List<Category2> category { get; set; }
    public Title2 title { get; set; }
    public Content content { get; set; }
    public List<Link2> link { get; set; }
}

public class Feed
{
    public string xmlns { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__xmlns$openSearch { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__xmlns$gsx { get; set; }
    public Id id { get; set; }
    public Updated updated { get; set; }
    public List<Category> category { get; set; }
    public Title title { get; set; }
    public List<Link> link { get; set; }
    public List<Author> author { get; set; }
    public OpenSearchTotalResults __invalid_name__openSearch$totalResults { get; set; }
    public OpenSearchStartIndex __invalid_name__openSearch$startIndex { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string encoding { get; set; }
    public Feed feed { get; set; }
}
```